# Changing a checkbox checked values (Loop not working)

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a javascript code that takes the value from one input field and changes all other inputs with same class with it, if the corresponding checkbox is checked.
The javascript is at the bottom, but still gets at all 3 buttons:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at change_numbr**

Any advice ?

**Code:**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check1">Check</label>
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number1">Number</label>
            <input id="number1" type="text" class="numbr" value="324">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('numbr1')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check2">Check</label>
            <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number2">Number</label>
            <input id="number2" type="text" class="numbr" value="85">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('numbr2')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check3">Check</label>
            <input id="check3" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number3">Number</label>
            <input id="number3" type="text" class="numbr" value="3">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('numbr3')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_numbr(selected_numbr) {
    var value_numbr = document.getElementById(selected_numbr).value;
    var total_numbr = document.getElementsByClassName("numbr");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < total_numbr.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(check[i]).checked) {
        document.getElementById(number[i]).value = value_numbr;

         }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're passing values to your function like `numbr1`, `numbr2`, and `numbr3`, but none of your elements have those for an ID. You do, however, have elements with IDs of `number1`, `number2`, and `number3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you look for:

```js
function change_numbr(selected_numbr) {

    var value_numbr = document.getElementById(selected_numbr).value;
    var total_numbr = document.getElementsByClassName("numbr");
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < total_numbr.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("check"+i).checked) {
        document.getElementById("label"+i).innerHTML  = value_numbr;

         }
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check1">Check</label>
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label id="label1" for="number1">Number</label>
            <input id="number1" type="text" class="numbr" value="324">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('number1')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check2">Check</label>
            <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label id="label2" for="number2">Number</label>
            <input id="number2" type="text" class="numbr" value="85">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('number2')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check3">Check</label>
            <input id="check3" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label id="label1" for="number3">Number</label>
            <input id="number3" type="text" class="numbr" value="3">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('number3')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In the future try to clarify variable names for a more clean an readeable code, ask if you have any doubts. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use string, `check` is not defined.
something like:

```
document.getElementById('check'+i).checked)
```

same goes for number:

```
document.getElementById('number'+i).value
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDs numbr1, numbr2, numbr3 not exists in the DOM. I think you pass the wrong ID to the Function change_numbr() in your code.

But I think this is just one problem.

Answer (score 0):

I change your code and it works.

Here the code I have tested.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function change_numbr(selected_numbr) {
    alert('ciaoooo');
    var value_numbr = document.getElementById(selected_numbr).value;
    console.log(value_numbr);
    var total_numbr = document.getElementsByClassName("numbr");
    console.log(value_numbr.length);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < total_numbr.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('check' + i).checked) {
        document.getElementById('number' + i).value = value_numbr;

         }
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check1">Check</label>
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number1">Number</label>
            <input id="number1" type="text" class="numbr" value="324">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('number1')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check2">Check</label>
            <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number2">Number</label>
            <input id="number2" type="text" class="numbr" value="85">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('number2')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check3">Check</label>
            <input id="check3" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number3">Number</label>
            <input id="number3" type="text" class="numbr" value="3">
            <button type="button" onClick="change_numbr('number3')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Look the difference with your old code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```js
function change_numbr(selected_numbr) {
    var value_numbr = document.getElementById(selected_numbr).value;
    var total_numbr = document.getElementsByClassName("numbr");
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= total_numbr.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('check'+i).checked) {
        document.getElementById('number'+i).value = value_numbr;
         }
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check1">Check</label>
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number1">Number</label>
            <input id="number1" type="text" class="numbr" value="324">
            <button type="button" onclick="change_numbr('number1')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check2">Check</label>
            <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number2">Number</label>
            <input id="number2" type="text" class="numbr" value="85">
            <button type="button" onclick="change_numbr('number2')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <label for="check3">Check</label>
            <input id="check3" type="checkbox" class="chkbox">           
            <label for="number3">Number</label>
            <input id="number3" type="text" class="numbr" value="3">
            <button type="button" onclick="change_numbr('number3')">click</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```